# How to better store multiple option values from a form in a database?

Tags: html, database, forms

I have to develop a web system. As every web system it has forms where the users will have to select one from many options, or many options altogether. They will also have a descriptive text and that data will be used in other parts within the system. So, it's data to be stored in a database in an information system. However, I don't know what's the best practice regarding multiple options.

Let me give you an example. Suppose I have the following:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">My first option</option>
    <option value="2">My second option</option>
    <option value="3">My third option</option>
</select>
```

This data is related to, say, a person. How do I represent this on my database? Should I use a separate table with the value id as the PK and a string with the description? Should I store the value only, the string only? I'm a bit lost here.

Thank you beforehand.

EDIT: My main concern is that creating an extra table will be a hassle. I'll have to create a related object with its corresponding DAO that only one class will be using. However using other methods seems like it won't escalate well and will create an overall mess.

Comment: This question is incredibly vague. There's no good way to answer it as you've written it-- the only answer one can give is "it depends". Be more specific-- about what kind of data you're storing, what kinds of queries you'd be doing on it, WHAT YOU'VE TRIED SO FAR (and why it doesn't work), etc.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I just edited my post so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got my answer.

What I can do, instead of everything, and since I'm working in Java, is to use an `enum` instead. The data is unlikely to change in the long run, so this is my safest bet.